# Setting An Order For Specific Fields Using SELECT and ORDER BY

Tags: oracle, select, order-by

So I'm writing a query to show the hire_date, job_id and last name where the last name= 'Matos' and 'Taylor and the hire_date is in ascending order.

When executing this code:

```
SELECT last_name, job_id, hire_date
FROM employee
WHERE last_name = 'Taylor', last_name = 'Matos'
ORDER BY hire_date ASC;
```

it throws this error:

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

While removing either last_names like this:

```
SELECT last_name, job_id, hire_date
FROM employee
WHERE last_name = 'Matos'
ORDER BY hire_date ASC;
```

shows the result only for one row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the last name condition as

```
last_name in ('Matos', 'Taylor')
```

or

```
(last_name = 'Matos' or last_name = 'Taylor')
```

Your syntax for multiple last names isn't supported.  (NB: the order of the Matos, Taylor isn't important.)

See: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/in.php